# JavaFX calculator RPN - RuntimeException after method invocation

Tags: java, javafx, postfix-notation

I'm trying to create a calculator using JavaFX and Reverse Polish Notation. The idea is to read input from user using TextField, then convert common infix form into postfix form, do the calculation and present output by pressing a button "equals". I wanted it to be able to do the operations on doubles. Example formula taken from the user is:
**((234*(7-3))/2)**
 after conversion to postfix form it should look like this: **234 7 3 - * 2 /**
After some troubles I've managed to do it, but only as a test using console.
When I've connected it with previously build JavaFX GUI, it throws RunTime Exception and I don't know why it is happening. So, I store String tokens in an ArrayList, here is my parsing method:

```
public void parseExpression(String expr) {
    char[] temp = expr.toCharArray();
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i=0;i<temp.length;i++) {
        if(temp[i]=='(' || temp[i]==')' || temp[i]=='+' || temp[i]=='-' || temp[i]=='*' || temp[i]=='/') {
            list.add(Character.toString(temp[i]));
        } else{
            stringBuffer.append(temp[i]);
            if ((i+1)<temp.length){
                if (temp[i+1]=='(' || temp[i+1]==')' || temp[i+1]=='+' || temp[i+1]=='-' || temp[i+1]=='*' || temp[i+1]=='/'){
                    String number = stringBuffer.toString();
                    stringBuffer.setLength(0);
                    list.add(number);
                }
            }
        }
    } 

    for (String str: list){
        System.out.print(str+" ");
    }
}
```

My postfix conversion method looks like this:

```
public void beginConvert(){
    convertToONP(list.get(0));
}

public void convertToONP(String current) {
    if (currIndex < list.size()) {
        String a;
        String c = current;
        if (c.equals("(")) {
            convertToONP(list.get(++currIndex));
            a = list.get(currIndex);
            convertToONP(list.get(++currIndex));
            ++currIndex;
            System.out.print(a+" ");
        } else {
            System.out.print(c+" ");
            ++currIndex;
        }
    }
}
```

And when I run these methods in a Test class:

```
public class Test {
    /*
     *my methods methods
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        String formula = "(234+(2*3))";
        test.parseExpression(formula);
        System.out.println();
        test.beginConvert();
    }
}
```

This is the output:
**( 234 + ( 2 * 3 ) ) 

234 2 3 * +**

But when I put these methods in a button's setOnAction method in the controller class connected to FXML file:

```
@FXML
public void equalsPressed(){
    calculator.parseExpression(formulaTextField.getText());
    calculator.beginConvert();
}
```

This is the output: 
**( 234 + ( 2 * 3 ) )**

> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 
>   Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 
>   at model.Calculator.beginConvert(Calculator.java:60)

Can someone explain to me why this is happening? I really appreciate any help you can provide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why your test version works, but:

It appears from the `beginConvert()` method that you have an instance field called `list`. You presumably initialize this somewhere (to an empty list?).

The `parseExpression()` method doesn't add any elements to the instance field `list`: it creates a local variable of the same name:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and then parses the expression and adds elements to the local list. The instance field `list` is never modified in `parseExpression().`

So (while it's impossible to know for certain, without seeing a complete example), you probably intend to initialize the *instance variable* in `parseExpression()`. Replace

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

with

```
list = new ArrayList<String>();
```